# Open source color code decoder

Tags: resource-request

Is there an open source color code decoder available somewhere?

For the surface code there's pymatching, for the color code there's...?

Comment: There is a paper: Decoder for the Triangular Color Code by Matching on a Möbius Strip but I could not see the mobius link via github